# How to pass Json serialized object to javascript (ASP.NET C#)

Tags: c#, .net, javascript

i have a method that returns a list of serialized objects in my page code behind

```
private string Get()
{
    JavaScriptSerializer jsonSerialiser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    string jsonString = SerializeToJason(UnavailabilityBusiness.Get(new DateTime()));
    return  jsonString ;    
}
```

i would like to pass this serialized objects to javascript

```
function getJson()
{
     ??????
}
```

How do I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write them out as a script, typically leveraging [ClientScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178207.aspx).

You would want to take care to register the script so that it renders before the consuming script.

Comment: Could you give an example please, i have tried everything i thought could have worked

Comment: @GigaP - sorry, I missed your request. Did you get it going or do you still need some guidance?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this guy wrote a utility class to do what you're trying to do ([Code Project Link](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/Generic_CS_JSON_generator.aspx)).

I have't really looked at it but you can get his source and have a look.

Good luck,

Patrick.